# Use of lambda expression in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to refactor this code to use lambda expression java 8

```java
for(int i = 0; i < customers.getCUSTOMER().size(); i++){
   if (customers.getCUSTOMER().get(i).getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger()
     < customers.getCUSTOMER().get(i).getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()){

        log.error("")
        throw new RuntimeException();
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041503/use-of-lamda-expression-in-java-8#57041503)

Comment: @Paul - it is an unchecked exception, so there are no problems throwing it.

Comment: By the way, you can't compare `BigInteger` using `<`

Comment: Okay, so `customers.getCUSTOMER().stream().filter(c -> c.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger().compareTo(c.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()) == -1).findAny().ifPresent(c -> { throw new RuntimeException(); });` should be enough.

Comment: @StephenC i first convert them to integer then use <, What is the nice way to check if greater than using BigInteger

Comment: Use the compareTo method.   But do you really need to use `BigInteger` at all?   Are you really expecting to support incomes > `9.223372e+18` cents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the elements of `customers.getCUSTOMER()`, which appears to be a `List` (and I assume for the purposes of this answer that it is one).  Presumably, then, you're going to process that list's stream:

```
customers.getCUSTOMER().stream()
```

you're using the `getINCOME()` of each element twice, and not any other aspect of it at all, so perhaps you want to map elements via that method.  Supposing that the elements of the customer list are of type `Customer`, that might be

```
        .map(Customer::getINCOME)
```

There are various ways to go from there, but since you're throwing an exception when a condition is satisfied, I'd personally go with `Stream.anyMatch()`:

```
        .anyMatch(x -> x.getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger().compareTo(
                x.getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()) < 0)
```

That produces a boolean result that tells you whether any element satisfies the condition, and it stops looking as soon as it finds one that does (and the predicate for the `anyMatch()` is a lambda).  You would use it in an `if` expression similar to the one you have now:

```
if (customers.getCUSTOMER().stream()
        .map(Customer::getINCOME)
        .anyMatch(x -> x.getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger().compareTo(
                x.getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()) < 0) {
    log.error("")
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Since you're throwing a `RuntimeException`, it would also be possible to do that with a lambda, inside the stream, but that's *not* generally possible if you're throwing a checked exception.  In the checked-exception case, something along the lines presented here is usually needful.

On the other hand, if you want to log information about the element that failed then you would need to do that inside the stream.  Additionally, in that case you might want to skip the `map()`.  You could instead `filter()` based on the predicate, and `findFirst()` among the elements, if any, remaining (or `findAny()` if you don't care whether it's the first that you report on). The result is an `Optional`, which you can process, if present, with another lambda:

```
customers.getCUSTOMER().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger().compareTo(
                x.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()) < 0)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(x -> {
            log.error(x.getName() + " invalid: net salary is larger than gross")
            throw new RuntimeException();
        });
```

Note that this does not solve the checked-exception problem.  You cannot throw a checked exception from inside the `ifPresent` lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
customers.getCUSTOMER().stream().forEach(customer -> {
    if(customer.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger() < customer.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()){
      log.error("");
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
});
```

You should also try renaming your methods using camelcase, e.g getIncome() to make it easier to read and conform to normal Java writing standards.

Answer (score 0):

```
customers.getCUSTOMER().forEach(customer -> {
        if (customer.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger() < 
             customer.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger()) {
            log.error("")
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
 });
```

A simple way

Another way using stream and Optional:

```
  customers.stream().filter(customer ->    
            customer.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger() < 
             customer.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger())
       .findAny().ifPresent(c -> {
           log.error("")
           throw new RuntimeException();
    });;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using java-8 streams, use `filter` for condition and `findFirst` to terminate after one match

```
customers.getCUSTOMER().stream()
                       .filter(c->c.getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1().toBigInteger() < c.getINCOME().getNETTSALMONTH1().toBigInteger())
                       .findFirst()
                       .ifPresent(cu->{
                               log.error("")
                               throw new RuntimeException();
                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need in this case is a `BiPredicate<TypeOfMonths>` which will look like this

```
BiPredicate<TypeOfMonths> biPredicate = (tom1, tom2) -> tom1.toBigInteger() < tom2.toBigInteger();
```

Then use it like this

```
boolean shouldThrowException = customers.getCUSTOMER()
                                        .stream()
                                        .anyMatch(cust -> {
                                            TypeOfMonth tom1 = getINCOME().getGROSSMONTH1();
                                            TypeOfMonth tom2 = getINCOME()..getNETTSALMONTH1();
                                            return biPredicate.test(tom1, tom2);
                                        });

if (shouldThrowException) {
    log.error("");
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```